# How to upload blinky program onto nRF9160-dk

Tags: nrf52, nrf91

I’m currently trying to flash the blinky code (found in the ‘Getting Started’ section) onto the nordic nrf9160-dk.

The error I’m getting is :
“error: cmake failed
create_nordic_project.py failed (1)”

When I looked online for help/clarification I saw a post from the nordic devzone forums saying that the ‘create_nordic_project.py failed (1)’ error arises when the wrong board name is picked in SEGGER Embedded Studio (SES). I looked at this link from Nordic: https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF_Connect_SDK/doc/latest/nrf/app_boards.html and tried all the boards that correspond to the nRF9160-dk and I’m still receiving the same error message.

I also saw on the nordic dev zone forums that it could help to go to SES to navigate to Target >> Connect J-Link >> Erase All to clear the board. I tried that and it didn’t change anything.

Any ideas on how to fix this error? For context I was able to successfully flash all of the ‘Getting Started’ sample programs onto the nRF52-dk.

Lastly, even though uploading the blinky program onto the nRF9160-dk is giving me an error message, when I just click on the blinky project I created for the nRF52-dk, LED3 on the nrf9160-dk starts blinking without me needing to upload it at all.This could be because the nrf9160-dk includes a nrf52840 board controller, explaining why the program uploads. However, none of the other ‘Getting Started’ programs I loaded onto the nRF52-dk automatically upload onto the board so I’m not really sure why that’s happening.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After you receive this error, go to the build menu and select "Show Build Log". There will be an error in there somewhere which gives more information. Usually it is due to bad prj.conf settings, or yes, perhaps some other error to do with the device tree generation.